# Best practice for clientside/server side encryption for form data

Tags: php, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, security

I am planning a project that requires the transmission of sensitive data from the client-side to the server-side, and then on to an AWS Simple Storage bucket.

This is my plan:

1. Using SSL/HTTP(S), the data can be posted securely via a web form, which is then retrieved by a PHP script on my web-server.
2. Once the data is received by the server, the PHP script will immediately send it to AWS using the AWS SDK for PHP with a directive to encrypt the data on the server-side with AES-256- See [AWS Encryption](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingEncryption.html).

The problem is that between steps 1 and 2, the data will not be encrypted because it has to hit my web-server first for processing. I'm thinking of having the script write the data into a text file on the server before sending it to AWS, then immediately deleting the temp file from the server after it is sent. Is there any risk in doing this? Is there a way to send a file-stream, rather than an actual file to an AWS Simple Storage bucket, thus avoiding the need to write a temp file to the server?

Am I overlooking better methods of achieving my original goal of data transmission that is encrypted 100% of the way?

Comment: If you're writing to S3 from the instance, that means you have AWS credentials on the instance that can be used to access S3.  Even though AWS might be encrypting the contents in S3, anybody who cracks your instance can still get access to the data using your AWS keys.  You might be able to reduce the risk a bit by using IAM credentials that have write-only permission to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Things stored in memory can also be written to disk without your knowledge if the system triggers swapping

Comment: What kind of client. The easiest answer is encrypt it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're committing something to disk, then a sufficiently motivated attacker can arrange to steal that file the moment it hits the drive platters - it's fairly trivial to get notified of any changes to a disk/directory on most any modern OS, so they can simply monitor your temp directory (wherever you're writing those files) and copy them out.

Even if you immediately delete the file, the file is still present in the storage system in various caches, and as "can be written over anytime" sectors on the disk platter. Until the data's been overwritten by something else, an even more dedicated attacker can still retrieve the file even after deletion.

Beyond that, someone with enough access rights could simply reach in your PHP process's memory space and extract the file from there.

So.. the question you have to ask yourself is "what is my threat model"? And "what data am I storing in this file?"

If the data includes credit card numbers, then you're already in violation of PCI standards - the CC number can **NEVER** be stored anywhere in plaintext/readable format.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. The info is personal in nature (not CC info), so no need to worry about PCI. it's more about confidentiality between client and consultant communication. I don't think the company is really that big of a target for hackers, much less extremely dedicated ones but I just want to be as diligent as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Not an encryption expert, so can't help there, but...

If you don't trust the webserver's physical security enough to rely on standard Unix system hardening, you probably need to get a better webserver.

Any encryption you use on the intermediate server will suffer from the fact that the decryption key must be stored on the server in order for the data to decrypted and then sent on to AWS. If the key is stealable, the data is not secure even when encrypted. If it's not stealable, then how can the data be stealable?

Forcing the system to use only RAM with no possibility of writing to disk is tricky and ignores the fact that someone with root access can also read data (with difficulty) directly from the RAM of the webserver process before it gets encrypyed.

Once someone has root, there's no real defence unless the key is stored elsewhere, so I would recommend using a public key in the browser and a private key within AWS. Forget about decrypting it half way. If AWS can't do that, then don't use it. [This post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/04/client-side-data-encryption-using-the-aws-sdk-for-java.html) suggests that they do, with a tutorial [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-S3/2850096021478074), but you'll need to use Java by the looks of it.